# Unity3D instantiate list of prefabs in new UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I am trying to make a custom list in *ScrollView*, but I can't manage to do it in new UI.
I have a prefab that is a *Panel* with 5 *Text* elements side by side. Now, there is *ScrollView* on scene with one horizontal and one vertical *Scrollbar* and I want to *Instantiate* 5 of those prefabs one below another so they look like a table.
Here is what I did, but it only instantiates them on top of each other and stretches them:

```
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        GameObject q = Instantiate(questionObjectModel) as GameObject;
        q.transform.parent = questionListHolder.GetComponent<Transform>();
    }
```

*questionObjectModel* is the *ScrollView* on the scene (I did try to set another *Panel* inside and_Istantiate_ prefabs on it).

**Edit:**
Ok, I have managed to set them not to be stretched. Only need to set them one below another now:

```
q.transform.SetParent(questionListHolder.transform, false);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it with help of a friend.
Inside of a *ScrollView* add new *Panel* and on add components *Vertical Layout Group* and *Content Size Filter* on that panel. When you do that, on prefab that you are instantiating set component *Layout Element* and set preferred size if you want to.
Then just instantiate prefab with:

```
        GameObject q = Instantiate(questionObjectModel) as GameObject;
        q.transform.SetParent(questionListHolder.transform, false);
```

You can see instantiating explanation on http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html

I hope it helps.